# Enable ttl in scala with elastic4s

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, ttl, elastic4s

I am using elastic4s to implement elastic search. I am trying to enable ttl but I couldn't figure it out how ? I mean yes _ttl enabled is going to be true but within the code where and how should I be implementing it ? I am using the latest version 1.3.2 for elastic4s

Answer (score 1):

If you already enabled it, when all you need is to pass it as a field when indexing documents, like:

```
index into "documents/doc" fields (
  "title" -> document.title,
  "description" -> document.description,
  "_ttl" -> 30.minutes.toMillis // TTL should be passed as milliseconds number
)
```

UPD: Also, there is special DSL support in elastic4s for ttl:

```
index into "documents/doc" ttl 30.minutes.toMillis fields (
  "title" -> document.title,
  "description" -> document.description
)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So in your example this entry will be deleted automatically after 30 minutes. Is that the case ? I was just trying it with 5 seconds or 1 minute and it does not delet it after ttl time passes ?

Comment: Its TTL will be equal 30 minutes, but there is some catch: elasticsearch will not delete it immediately after expiring. There is some interval at which elasticsearch delete them, see last paragraph in http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-ttl-field.html

Comment: Also, in elastic4s 1.4.9 onwards, you can use a normal scala duration for ttl, eg   `client.execute {   index into "electronics/phone" fields "vender" -> "blackberry" ttl 1.second
    }`